# Go html template

Tags: html, golang

Есть пример программы, который запускает http-сервер и показывает html страницу. Проблема в том, что при заходе на по адресу сервера(`127.0.0.1:8080`), страница не отображается, как бы пустое окно в браузере. Ошибок при этом нет ни в консоли, ни в браузере. Компиляция тоже без ошибок.

**Сам пример:**

```
Go
├── default.go
├── Go
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

---

**default.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
    }   
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

---

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head><meta></meta></head>

<body bgcolor=#f2f2f2>

<p>test</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а если сделать запрос ручками (то есть курлом с консоли), то что то выдает?

Comment: Пустую строчку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы ошибки **недообработали**. А если бы внимательнее к ним относились, то заметили бы, что `t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)` **вернул ошибку**!

Если обработать эту ошибку и попросить деталей, всплывает занимательная деталь:

```
template_error := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
if template_error != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, template_error.Error())
    fmt.Fprintf(w, t.DefinedTemplates())
}
```

---

```
html/template: "index" is undefined; defined templates are: "index.html"
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь всё работает.